# How to retrieve the last sent message from myself in XMPP using xmppframework?

Tags: ios, swift, xmppframework

I want to retrieve the last message I sent to someone in XMPP. 
I have written this code, but it fetches all sent messages:

```
let query = try? XMLElement(xmlString: "<query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:2'/>")
let iq = XMLElement.element(withName: "iq") as? XMLElement
iq?.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "set")
iq?.addAttribute(withName: "from", stringValue: "f.talebi@x.ir")
iq?.addAttribute(withName: "max", stringValue: "1")
iq?.addAttribute(withName: "id", stringValue: "GetLastUserMessage")


if let aQuery = query {
     iq?.addChild(aQuery)
}

xmppStream.send(iq!)
```

Answer (score 2):

first you should have xmppMessageArchiveManagement module:

`var xmppMAM: XMPPMessageArchiveManagement!`

then active it

`xmppMAM.activate(xmppStream)`

after that you can use protocol function of xmppMessageArchiveManagementDelegate

`extension someClass: XMPPMessageArchiveManagementDelegate {
    func xmppMessageArchiveManagement(_ xmppMessageArchiveManagement: XMPPMessageArchiveManagement, didReceiveMAMMessage message: XMPPMessage) {
    }
    func xmppMessageArchiveManagement(_ xmppMessageArchiveManagement: XMPPMessageArchiveManagement, didFinishReceivingMessagesWith resultSet: XMPPResultSet) {
    }
}`

now you can create packet and send them and two above function will catch the packet of server :
caution:you should use mam:1 instead of mam:2 and use messageArchiveManagement for all retrieving tasks.example:for retrieving your last message build this packet and use mam for sending it.

```
`let value = DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: youJid)
 let child = DDXMLElement(name: "field")
 child.addChild(value)
 child.addAttribute(withName: "var", stringValue: "with")
 let set = XMPPResultSet(max: 1, before: "")
 xmppMam.retrieveMessageArchive(at: nil, withFields: [child], with: set)`
```

Comment: Thanks. but I don't have XmppMessageArchiveModule